# wso2 dss 3.5.0 subtracting hours from datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

data source = dateTime 2016-02-**26** 00:00:00.0

dss return = dateTime 2016-02-**25**T**09**:00:00.000-03:00

I would like to know if there is any settings to be made in the tool itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me briefly explain what you have received from the WSO2 Data Services Server (DSS).

It's not subtracting some hours from the date stored in your database. Actually, DSS server appends time zone information to your date fields.

Do you really want your date fields without time zone information? At the moment, I would like to suggest (as a workaround )  manually remove  time zone information once you receive the response from the DSS  server.

In the meantime, I have raised a public JIRA [1](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1191) regarding this issue and will notify the progress of it via this question.